# how to accomplish this?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

having below data

[image]

with below format

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample](
    [CCMPNY] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [CCUST#] [numeric](7, 0) NOT NULL,
    [RDDYSR] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [CBLNAM] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [CCYCLE] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [RDSIZE] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [RDCHGC] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [RDDAY] [numeric](1, 0) NOT NULL,
    [RDROUT] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [RDQTY] [numeric](5, 0) NOT NULL
```

how can I get below layout

[image]

Columns Marked in red

```
FREQ: "Count" of Days in "RDDYSR" field
LIFTS: "Lifts" = "RDQTY" times "Freq"
VOLUME: "Volume" = "RDQTY" times "RDSIZE" times "Freq"

Week Days columns: 
MON: If "RDDYSR" includes "M", "RDQTY" times "RDSIZE", else "blank".  
TUE: If "RDDYSR" includes "T", "RDQTY" times "RDSIZE", else "blank", etc.
```

**Notes**

```
that each "CCUST" generates only one data line unless 
(1) there are multiple "RDCHGC" values (CCUST 43), 
(2) there are multiple "RDSIZE" values (CCUST 10723); or, 
(3) there are multiple "FREQ" values (no example).
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you searched for anything? How numeric is `RDSIZE`, e.g. could it be '-0', 'IV', 'pi'? Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: what I could have done so far is removing the dashes from RDDYSR field, That way is easy to count week days.

Comment: That's a start. You'll probably want to use a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression to help out with the day columns, e.g. `case when CharIndex( 'M', RDDYSR ) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast( RDSIZE as Int ) else NULL end`. Note that it is generally considered a bad practice to mash arbitrary data types together, e.g. storing a size in a `VARCHAR(2)` or having a single that returns either the result of a numeric calculation (`RDQTY * RDSIZE`) as a string or the word `blank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for a little bit simply. I'm not sure what your identifier for Sunday is so I've commented this out with --

```
select CCUST# CCUST, CBLNAM,RDCHGC, RDQTY, RDSIZE, Len(Replace(RDDYSR, '-', '')) FREQ, 
RDQTY * Len(Replace(RDDYSR, '-', '')) LIFTS, 
RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) * Len(Replace(RDDYSR, '-', '')) Volume, RDDYSR,
Case when CHARINDEX('M', RDDYSR) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Mon,
Case when CHARINDEX('T', RDDYSR) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Tue,
Case when CHARINDEX('W', RDDYSR) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Wed,
Case when CHARINDEX('H', RDDYSR) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Thu,
Case when CHARINDEX('F', RDDYSR) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Fri,
Case when CHARINDEX('S', RDDYSR) > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Sat
--,Case when CHARINDEX(RDDYSR, 'X') > 0 then RDQTY * Cast(RDSIZE as int) end as Sun   --Whatever Sunday identifier is

from Sample

Group by CCUST#, CBLNAM, RDCHGC, RDQTY, RDSIZE, RDDYSR
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cdb92/1/0

Comment: @ChistianBarron please read my notes. your query works fine but is not grouping as my Notes indicate

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit. Adding a simple Group By at the bottom should sort that out (see updated above). SQL Fiddle is also updated

Comment: What could be generating this error message?   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.' to data type int.

Comment: It has a full stop after the 1. So in your table you must have a full stop after the 1 in one of the fields. Really if you're only keeping whole numbers in these columns they should be set to int rather than varchar

Comment: Did you make sure you changed all of them to this? It could be that some rows have other invalid characters in them other than full stop

Comment: has it for RDSIZE,  I did this Cast(Replace(RDSIZE, '.', '') as int) and solved the error, now my problem is that how can I get blank for NULL under week days columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78203/discussion-between-cojimarmiami-and-christian-barron).

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
SELECT CCUST
,CBLNAM
,RDCHGC
,RDQTY
,RDSIZE
,LEN(REPLACE(RDDYSR,'-','')) AS FREQ
,COUNT(RDDYSR)*RDQTY AS LIFTS
,RDSIZE * RDQTY * LEN(REPLACE(RDDYSR,'-','')) AS VOLUME
,FIRSTRDDYSR AS RDDYSR,FIRSTRDROUT AS RDROUT
,CASE WHEN (FIRSTRDDYSR LIKE 'M______') THEN RDQTY * RDSIZE END AS MON 
,CASE WHEN (FIRSTRDDYSR LIKE '_T_____') THEN RDQTY * RDSIZE END AS TUE
,CASE WHEN (FIRSTRDDYSR LIKE '__W____') THEN RDQTY * RDSIZE END AS WED
,CASE WHEN (FIRSTRDDYSR LIKE '___H___') THEN RDQTY * RDSIZE END AS THU
,CASE WHEN (FIRSTRDDYSR LIKE '____F__') THEN RDQTY * RDSIZE END AS FRI
,CASE WHEN (FIRSTRDDYSR LIKE '_____S_') THEN RDQTY * RDSIZE END AS SAT
FROM
(
    SELECT S.*, T.RDROUT AS FIRSTRDROUT, T.RDDYSR AS FIRSTRDDYSR FROM
    [SAMPLE] S
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CCUST, RDROUT, RDDYSR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ccust ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) N
        FROM SAMPLE
    ) T ON S.CCUST = T.CCUST AND N = 1
) Tbl

GROUP BY CCUST, CBLNAM, RDCHGC, RDQTY, RDSIZE, RDDYSR, FIRSTRDDYSR, FIRSTRDROUT
```

Comment: using your query I am getting this error Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: This query worked perfectly for me. I think your best bet is to just figure out which line is breaking it. One of your numeric datatypes is probably a varchar.

Comment: @Stephan please see how customer BRINKMANN HARDWARE get the same RDDYSR for each instance even though the last one is different...... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f8e8/6