# how to get a percentage depending on a column value?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Update 05/18/15**

Having a column with customers names listed on it. How can I get a percentage based in one customer per date? For example

```
    CustomerName     Date
    Sam              04/29/15
    Joy              04/29/15
    Tom              04/29/15
    Sam              04/29/15
    Oly              04/29/15
    Joy              04/29/15
                     04/29/15
    Sam              04/29/15
                     04/29/15
    Sam              04/29/15
    Oly              04/29/15
    Sam              04/29/15
    Oly              04/30/15
    Joy              05/01/15
```

Notice that my column has 12 records, 2 of them are blanks, but they won't count on the percentage, just the ones that has name. I would like to know what percentage represents Sam from the total(in this case 10 records, so Sam % will be 50).

Query should return

```
Date             Percentage
04/29/15            50
04/30/15            0
05/01/15            0
```

**Update**

I don't really care about the other Customers, so lets treat them as one. Just need to know what percentage is Sam from the total list.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there an Id or primary key available? Can we assume, that the date is always the identical for all affacted rows?

Comment: when you say blank, do you mean `null` or empty space?

Comment: when I say blank I mean empty space @ughai, thanks

Comment: @Serv there is no primary key and Date will vary because data is for a whole month, so I need to know what percentage Sam represents over the other customers per day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone seems to be using subqueries or derived tables. This should perform well and it's easy to follow. Try it out:

```
DECLARE @CustomerName VARCHAR(5) = 'Sam';

SELECT  [Date],
        @CustomerName AS CustomerName,
        percentage = CAST(CAST(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerName = @CustomerName THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20)) + '%'
FROM @yourTable
WHERE CustomerName != ''
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Results:

```
Date       CustomerName percentage
---------- ------------ ---------------------
2015-04-29 Sam          50%
2015-04-30 Sam          0%
2015-05-01 Sam          0%
```

Comment: Lets treat the other customers as one, I just need the percentage of Sam over the whole list grouped by Date, Thanks

Comment: Okay I think I got it now.

Comment: getting this error 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name @Stephan. I am running sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Sorry CONCAT is only allowed in 2012 and above. I'll fix it.

Comment: what about if for Date 04/30/15 there is no Sam, it should return 0%, Could you please twist your code to reflect that. Please see my updated post @Stephan

Comment: you are awesome, worked like a charm @Stephan. Could you please help me with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831283/how-to-accomplish-this/29853411#29853411

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the numbers per person+day in a subquery:

```
select  Date
,       CustomerName
,       100.0 * cnt / sum(cnt) over (partition by date)
from    (
        select  Date
        ,       CustomerName
        ,       count(*) cnt
        from    table1
        where   CustomerName <> ''
        group by
                Date
        ,       CustomerName
        ) t1
```

This prints:

```
Date                    CustomerName 
----------------------- ------------ ---------------------------------------
2015-04-29 00:00:00.000 Joy          20.000000000000
2015-04-29 00:00:00.000 Oly          20.000000000000
2015-04-29 00:00:00.000 Sam          50.000000000000
2015-04-29 00:00:00.000 Tom          10.000000000000

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: how can I get this working only for Sam, I don't really care about the other customers. Just need to know what percentage Sam represent @Andomar, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName <> '' AND Date = '04/29/15')
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerName = 'Sam'
    AND Date = '04/29/15'
```

If you want to get the `count` per date, you can use this

```
SELECT T.Date,((ISNULL(CustomerCount,0) * 100) / TotalCount)
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount,Date 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CustomerName <> ''
GROUP BY Date
)T
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Customer
WHERE CustomerName = 'Sam'
GROUP BY Date 
)C
ON T.Date = C.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select name, date, (100.0 * count(*)) / 
    (select count(*) from table t2 
     where name is not null and name <> '' and t2.date = t1.date) 
from table t1
where name is not null and name <> ''
group by name, date
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the users

```
SELECT 
        (COUNT(*) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName <> '') as [percent],
         CustomerName
    FROM Customer group by CustomerName
```

for specifice user

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(*) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer WHERE CustomerName <> '') as [percent],
     CustomerName
FROM Customer where CustomerName ='Sam'
```

Comment: The OP asks for "one customer per date". So `count(*)` is not an option I think